# Time complexity for n elements

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree, nodes

I have these 2 questions which I'm stuck on. I have an idea of how the search works but not entirely sure. I wrote what I knew but I don't think it seems 100% accurate or answers the question.

1) The first time you run algorithm A on a dataset of n elements; it is faster than
algorithm B. The second time you run algorithm A on a dataset of n elements; it is slower than
algorithm B. Explain how this is possible. Give an example for algorithm A and algorithm B.

2) If both have n nodes and are sorted smallest to largest, will it be faster to find
the largest value in a sorted linked list or a minimum-level BST? Explain.

This is what I think for the above questions. Please correct me if I am wrong or missing any KEY information.

1) Algorithm A is a linear search (checks every element for a match). Algorithm B sorts the data and stores in memory before using binary search. For every consequent search, Algorithm B would be faster because the binary search is generally faster than a linear search.

2) if the list is ordered from min to max, it will become O(1) if you further have the tail pointer. The reason is that the max element is the last one in the linked list. Thus you have to traverse to the tail (O(n)).

Sorry if I broke any rules but I'm asking after a long time.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: your comment `Sorry if I broke any rules` sound to me like: `sorry, if I killed you` :P

Comment: Also, you can answer these questions on your own if you spend some more time knowing the algorithms and data structures. For now, just assume whatever seems more accurate according to your logic. According to me, there can be a lot of reasons for B being faster in consecutive runs, result storage is one among it, and offcourse it totally depends on the algorithm. Honestly, the second question seems dumb to be. But ya keep asking such questions to yourself and not on stackoverflow(because you can get their answers over internet)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your guesses are correct. For the sake of completeness you may add O(log(n)) for the binary search.